# Property 'coords' does not exist on type 'MouseEvent'. In Angular2-google-maps marker event

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have added mapClicked event of angular2-google-maps map. The code is as below:

```
mapClicked($event: MouseEvent) {
this.markers.push({
  lat: $event.coords.lat,
  lng: $event.coords.lng,
  draggable: false
});
```

}

I am getting compile time error while serving my ionic 2 app with "ionic serve".

Thanks in advance,
AB

Comment: Why should a mouseclick have a lat/long? Follow your compiler's advise

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is just Typescript complaining since the [default MouseEvent interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) doesn't have the `coords` property, but since you're using `angular2-google-maps` you know the `coords` property will be there ([ng2 google maps MouseEvent interface](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/interfaces/MouseEvent.html)) so you can avoid that compile time error by just using `any` instead of `MouseEvent` like this:

```
mapClicked($event: any) {
this.markers.push({
  lat: $event.coords.lat,
  lng: $event.coords.lng,
  draggable: false
});
```

---

**EDIT**

Just like **[@Bruno Garcia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1977143/bruno-garcia)** pointed out, a better way to solve this would be to import the proper interface from the AGM library. That way you could use typings and the autocomplete feature of the IDE for that `MouseEvent` event.

But instead of importing the `MouseEvent` as he described in his answer, **I'd prefer to use an alias, to avoid any confusion with the *default MouseEvent interface***:

```
import { MouseEvent as AGMMouseEvent } from '@agm/core';
```

and then just use that alias:

```
mapClicked($event: AGMMouseEvent) { ... }
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: "Module '"@agm/core"' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'."

Comment: @Sebastián could you please check [this Github issue](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/issues/1850)? There it's said "correct, instead of MouseEvent, switch to `google.maps.MouseEvent`".

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is correct in pointing out that the default MouseEvent doesn't have a `coords` property.

But AGM does ship with its own `MouseEvent` interface which does contain a [coords](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/interfaces/MouseEvent.html#coords) property of type `LatLngLiteral` as expected.
You just need to import it:

`import {MouseEvent} from "@agm/core";`

Then TypeScript's warning will go away and you'll have typings for the $event argument.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for pointing that out :) I've edited the answer to include this information (although using an alias instead of importing the `MouseEvent` as it is).

Comment: ggetting error while importing package Module '"../../../node_modules/@agm/core/agm-core"' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'

Answer (score 2):

Check your `@agm/core installed version`.

Use this one:
`npm i @agm/core@1.1.0`