# javascript: how to get data from event (MouseEvent)?

Tags: javascript, events

I receive a MouseEvent with following data

```
coords : { lat:1234, lng: 5678 }
```

My function is

```
onCircleClicked($event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log($event); // works

}
```

How to retrieve coords from $event?
If I write $event.coords.lat but coords is not recognised and so not compile.

Can anyone help?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: You need to post more DATA about your subject. Give tags and more relevant source code... If you wanna quick answer from community.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453293/property-coords-does-not-exist-on-type-mouseevent-in-angular2-google-maps-m