# Importing MouseEvent from @agm/core

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, agm

I want to add markers on a Google map in angular using agm module. I've found an implementation of how to do it using the map mapClick event. But I can't import MouseEvent from @agm/core. VsCode says the module doesn't have such exported member. Searched for  issues l'île that  here on stack and Google but I'm kinda surprised no one raised such an issue before.
Please help !
thanks in advance

Here is the code

```
mapClicked($event: MouseEvent) {
  this.markers.push({
    lat: $event.coords.lat,
    lng: $event.coords.lng,
    draggable: true
  });
}
```

Comment: Because it's a global type in the `google.maps` namespace. There's nothing to `import`.

Comment: But in the implementation i found they imported it. I'm a newbye to JavaScript and all that stuff. I'm trying to get sense of all this. Help me understand a bit more

Comment: Well, `@agm/core` refers to it as `google.maps.MouseEvent` [Example](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/blob/7982bfbcf0abeff3f2b77f03300a7b7e97fec9ce/packages/core/src/lib/directives/marker.ts#L128). What implementation are you talking about?

Comment: Check this link please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453293/property-coords-does-not-exist-on-type-mouseevent-in-angular2-google-maps-m

Comment: That's 3 years old. It's either out of date or plain wrong.

Comment: Ok got  it but check also this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo look at the top of the component file

Answer (score 0):

Usage will depend on the version of AGM.

Your StackBlitz example shows `"@agm/core": "1.0.0"`

You are likely using [3.0.0-beta.0](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/compare/1.1.0...3.0.0-beta.0). This should do what you are expecting

```typescript
  mapClicked($event: google.maps.MouseEvent): void {
    this.markers.push({
      lat: $event.latLng.lat(),
      lng: $event.latLng.lng(),
      draggable: true
    });
  }
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much ! Your answer would've helped me somehow. I did change the version of @agm/core  in my package.json and issues went away. It seems my version of @agm/core  was unstable, which cause the issues.