# How to import MouseEvent in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, maps

```
import { MapsAPILoader, MouseEvent} from '@agm/core';
```

I am trying to import MouseEvent in angular 9 but getting error

> Error: 'MouseEvent' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
> Module '"@agm/core"' has no exported member 'MouseEvent'.ts(2305)

Comment: Did you import the `{ AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';` , in your app.module?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63806723/importing-mouseevent-from-agm-core